# Powershell script to change the format of all files in a folder from Unicode to ANSI

Tags: powershell

Can someone give me a Powershell script that will change the format of all files in a folder from Unicode to ANSI?  Here is a sample folder structure:

```
c:\DBObjects
  +StoredProcs
      - sp1.sql
      - sp2.sql
      - sp3.sql
  +Views
     - v1.sql
     - v2.sql
  .Functions
     - fn1.sql
     - fn2.sql
```

I tried the following script for one file and it worked. However it will create another file:

```
Get-Content sp1.sql -encoding Unicode | Set-Content sp1_Ansi.sql -encoding ASCII
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
Set-Content sp1.sql -Encoding ASCII -Value (Get-Content sp1.sql)
```

Note that the entire file will be read into memory temporarily. If that's not acceptable, you'll need to use the pipeline method to write to a new file, then delete the old file, and rename the new file to the old file's name.

Comment: It worked! The following script forked for all files in one folder. `ls *.sql | forearch {sc $_ -encoding asciii -value(gc $_)}` . Can you tell me how to loop through all files in the subdirectories as well? Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out. `ls -re -include *.sql | forearch {sc $_ -encoding ascii -value(gc $_)} `.  Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.  Thank you!

Comment: @rk1962, here is how I do it via files wild-cards (*.sql in this case): `Get-ChildItem *.sql | % { Get-Content $_ | Set-Content "$($_.basename)-ascii.sql" -encoding ASCII }`